# Count Max with criteria in JPQL

Tags: hibernate, jpa, count, jpql

Hi I have a OneToMany association (User---Membership),
and I need to found the User with more memberships which attribute Membership.status is equals to 'ACCEPTED'.

I thought in this:

```
@Query("select u from User u join u.memberships m where count(m) = "
        + "(select max(count(m1)) from User u1 join u1.memberships m1 where m1.status ="
        + " 'ACCEPTED') and m.status = 'ACCEPTED'")
```

Console prints:

```
2015-10-26 16:45:13,514 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 1111, SQLState: HY000
2015-10-26 16:45:13,514 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - SQL Error: 1111, SQLState: HY000
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
2015-10-26 16:45:13,514 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Invalid use of group function
2015-10-26 16:45:13,514 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - Invalid use of group function
```

Could u help me with this query? Thanks.

Comment: and the full exception, stack trace, the SQL invoked by JPA implementation?

Comment: I didn't put it because only says that I don't have idea to do this query.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED:**
try to use this query:

```
SELECT u FROM user u
LEFT JOIN FETCH u.memberships  m
WHERE m.status = 'ACCEPTED'
AND u.memberships.size = (SELECT max(u1.memberships.size) FROM user u1)
```

Comment: This could work but not is that I ask. All memberships of the same User not have 'ACCEPTED' status, then, when you calls 
`u.memberships.size = (select ....)` you are taking into account that all u.memberships have the same status. And status is a property of Membership, you can't do `u1.status`

Comment: Doesn't work as expected, this query extract the maximum size of a membership but doesn't take into account the criteria (m.status = 'ACCEPTED'). Thanks

The most aproximation I had, It was in the opposite of the relationship:

select distinct m.student from Membership m where m.status = 'ACCEPTED' group by m.student) order by count(m);

This give me a ordered array, and I only have to search in the top.

Comment: Thank you for all, if you find exactly a query, comment me. :)